# The popup values are not displayed? How to resolve it?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

I am working in asp.net core. And I am using typescript. I am using the select2 option. But the values are not displayed ie)the popup is not displayed.

HTML:-

```
 <select class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;">
        <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
            <ul class="select2-selection__rendered"><li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li></ul></span></span>
        <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
```

Script:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
</script>
```

style:

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

script:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code. Can anyone suggest what mistakes I have done?

Is there any example (complete code) for select2?

Comment: can anyone suggest the answer?

Answer (score 0):

How to make this example work:

1. You don't need to use

   `<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;"> 
   ... 
   </span>`

because it will be auto-generated by `select2()`.

2. You should put `select2` in `$(document).ready` like below

   `<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
       });
   </script>`

You can see [working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juoz96kn/1/) here. Also tested it in ASP.NET Core project and it worked also.

Also you can use useful properties for`select2` like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2(
        {
            width: "300px", //can set width with this parameter
            maximumSelectionLength: 3, //can selet maximum 3 items
            placeholder: "Select the state"
        }
    );
});
```